# Extracting certain text from html file

Tags: java, html, parsing

I want to extract texts from a html file that are placed between parapraph(p) and link(a href) tags.I want to do it **without** java regex and html parsers.I thougth

```
while ((word = reader.readLine()) !=null) { //iterate to the end of the file
    if(word.contains("<p>")) { //catching p tag
        while(!word.contains("</p>") { //iterate to the end of that tag
            try { //start writing
                out.write(word);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not working.The code seems pretty valid to me.How the reader can catch the "p" and "a href" tags.

Comment: 1) always catch your exceptions -- never leave that block empty, else who knows what could be messing up in the try. 2) Put in println's or use a debugger to test the state of your variables inside of your while loop. To treat a problem, first you must diagnose the cause. 3) For my money, I'd use an HTML parser like JSoup to make my life easier. Why re-invent the wheel with a solution that is almost always going to be guaranteed to be kludgy?

Answer (score 3):

The problems start when you have something like this `<p>blah</p>` in a single line. One simple solution would be to change all the `<` to `\n<` - something like this:

```
boolean insidePar = false;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
    for(String word in line.replaceAll("<","\n<").split("\n")){
        if(word.contains("<p>")){
            insidePar = true;
        }else if(word.contains("</p>")){
            insidePar = false;
        }
        if(insidePar){ // write the word}
    }
}
```

Still I'd also recommend using a parser library like @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Edit: I've updated the code so it's a bit closer to a working version, but probably there
will be more problems along the way.

Comment: Why <p>blah</p> cause problems with that code?I dont understand.

Comment: @cane-r if you have the opening and closing tags in the same line then both conditions  (`word.contains("<p>")` and `word.contains("</p>")`) are true, so `out.write(word);` never gets called.

Comment: @cane-r Apart from that problem you need to place `reader.readLine()` somewhere in the inner loop - otherwise it will be writing out the same word over and over again till the world ends.

Comment: @cane-r I've edited the code so in my answer you can see what I mean.

Comment: One note: in Java there is no *in* keyword. The *foreach* loop is: `for (type item : iterableCollection)`

Comment: @informatik01 you're right! I've been writing too much in R lately :)

Answer (score 0):

I think using a library for this will be easier. use this http://jsoup.org/ . You can also parse String